# C# - entityFramework - filling up a list of values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I have an entity like:

```
public class Search
{
    public String FirstName {get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public Guid CId { get; set; }
}
```

and in the corresponding Search table, for each PersonId, I have many CIds. So if i

```
select * from Search where FirstName = 'D'
```

i get few rows of data, something like:

```
PersonId       CId       FirstName
8888888       2222222     D
8888888       4444444     D
8888888       3333333     D
```

Is there anyway to fill the entity with a list of CIds, instead of fetching a one "Search" for every row?

in other words, is there anyway to have the "Search" entity as:

```
   public class Search
{
    public String FirstName {get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public Guid[] CId { get; set; }
}
```

and get one PersonId and a list of CIds??

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried to use GroupBy clause?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334.aspx

Comment: yes.. but In my case, I can't use Groupby since if i want to use it, I need to do something like:  dbSet.Searches.GroupBy(s => s.PersonId).Select(a => a.FirstOrDefault()) and in this case, I lose CIds beside the first one and I need them..

Answer (score 0):

```
    var personId = "888888";
    var search = new Search {PersonId = personId };
    search.CId = DBContext.Search.Where(x => x.PersonId = personId).Select(x => x.CId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Henrique said, you can use groupby clause, but entity doesn't support group by so you need this and make a new class for the objet you are looking for:

```
 var results = ctx.Searches.Where(s => s.FirstName == "D")
                                    .AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.PersonId)
                                    .Select(p => new SearchResult{
                                                    FirstName = p.FirstOrDefault().FirstName,
                                                    PersonId = p.Key.Value,
                                                    CId = p.Select(z => z.CId).ToArray()
                                                }).ToList();
```

And this could be the class

```
class SearchResult 
    {
        public String FirstName {get; set; }
        public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
        public Guid[] CId { get; set; }
    }
```